# Pointers to pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Hello guys can someone explain why while declaring pointers to pointer we need to use `**` why cant we use only single `*` to point a pointer to another pointer or is it just a syntax related issue E.g

```
int main()
{
    int a=5,*b,*c;
    b=&a;
    c=&b    //Why cant this simply doesn't make c point to memory location of b with the above pointer declaration why is there a need to declare c as **c
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following codes:

```
int a=5,*b,**c;
b=&a;
c=&b;
```

We have:

```
    +---+
a   | 5 |  <-- value
    +---+
    |100|  <-- address
    +---+

    +---+
*b  |100|  <-- value
    +---+
    |200|  <-- address
    +---+

    +---+
**c |200|  <-- value
    +---+
    |300|  <-- address
    +---+
```

When you store a's address in b, b's value is a's address. But b has it's own address (200). 
c can store b's address as it's value. But c has it's own address too (300).

`printf("%x", &c);` will give you: 300

Deferencing *c will get you down "1 level" and give you 100 (get value of address 200)

Deferencing **c will get you down 1 more level and give you 5 (get value of address 100)

---

If you try to use *c instead of **c to hold *b, how are you able to deference all the way down to reach value 5?

**Testing the codes on a compiler:**

```
printf("Address of a: %x\n", &a);
printf("Address of b: %x\n", &b);
printf("Address of c: %x\n", &c);

printf("Value of a: %d\n", a);            
printf("Value of b: %x\n", b);  
printf("Value of c: %x\n", c);
```

**Output:**

```
Address of a: 28ff44
Address of b: 28ff40
Address of c: 28ff3c
Value of a: 5
Value of b: 28ff44
Value of c: 28ff40
```

Comment: very well explained. I must admit

Answer (score 2):

In this case

```
int main()
{
    int a=5,*b,*c;
    b=&a;
    c=&b;
}
```

Here `b` points to `a` and `c` points to `b`. It is what you have commented in the commented.

> c still points to the memory location of b.

The catch is : When you de-reference `b` i.e `*b = a = 5`. 
But When you de-reference `c` i.e `*c = b = &a`. So When you dereference `c` the output would be address of a instead of the value of the variable a

PS : you will face this warning when compiling the code `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type`

Answer (score 1):

You have your answer in your question only.

1. `pointer` to variable , use of `*`
2. `pointers to pointer` of a variable , use `**`

Details:

`**` is not a *new* operator. it's a combination of `*` and `*`. In case 2. as per your terminology, you can think of

```
only single * to point a pointer to another pointer
```

as in

```
int * to an inother int * ==> int **
```

---

EDIT:

as per your code

```
int main()
{
    int a=5,*b,*c;
    b=&a;
    c=&b;
}
```

1. `b` is a pointer to `int`. You can store the address of `int` there, and `a` is an `int`. Perfect.
2. `c` is a pointer to `int`. You can store the address of `int` there, and `b` is a pointer to  `int`. Not accepted.

To make point 2 work, you need to declare `c` as a pointer to `int *`, right? The notation for the same is `int **`.

Answer (score 1):

Every level of indirection needs a level of dereferencing. So for:

```
T*** x = ...;
```

you would need:

```
***x
```

to get to `T&`.

If you had a pointer to pointer and you saved it in:

```
T* x = ...;
T* y = &x;
```

it would mean that `*ptr` leads to `T&`, while it really leads to another `T*`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to think of pointers-to-pointers:  imagine how it works in memory.   Here's a little snippet that shows what I mean:

```
int TheInteger = 123;
int *p = &TheInteger;
int **pp = &p;

printf("The value at memory location &pp (0x%x) is 0x%x (pp).  This value (which we assigned as &p (0x%x) is 0x%x (p).  This value, in turn, we assign as &TheInegeter (0x%x) points to the 'instance' of TheInteger, which is %d", &pp, pp, &p, p, &TheInteger, TheInteger);
```

The output of this would be:

```
The value at memory location &pp (0x657e588) is 0x657e594 (pp).  This value (which we assigned as &p (0x657e594) is 0x657e5a0 (p).  This value, in turn, we assign as &TheInegeter (0x657e5a0) points to the 'instance' of TheInteger, which is 123
```

Now, to go back to your original question, you cannot declare a variable as being a pointer when the value you're setting it to is a pointer-to-a-pointer.  In other words, in your example, you set 'b' as a pointer to a -- so, you can't tell the compiler that 'c' is just a pointer and then try to set it to a value that the compiler knows is a pointer-to-a-pointer.